# Machine Learning and Deep Learning(neural nets)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

> "If you know Machine Learning, then you will not believe in Deep
>   Learning(artificial neural nets). If you believe in Deep Learning, that
>   means you don't understand Machine Learning"

Am I right? (this is not a subjective question)

Reasons (Upon request by Florian)

Deep learning and neural nets is an incomplete as a theory due to following reason

1. The solutions that fit training data are infinite. We don't have precise mathematical equation that is satisfied by only a single one and that we can say generalizes best. Simply speaking we don't know which generalizes best.

**On being put on hold, I am clarifying this :**

@Tim and others, Ah I see What you are getting at. The word 'believe'.....i used it in a totally an informal way, in the sense that, "I dont believe means, I dont accept it as a theory"....and don't want it to have any bearing on its practicality. I clarify, I am not in anyway intending to say that they are not practically useful, infact they are in much vogue in many practical applications, which everyone knows. No issues with that. I am talking in a theoretical sense, some things we cannot accept as a theory in some abstract sense, although they may be very useful in parcticality. By using word, "believe" i mean "accepting as a theory", and not bearing anything on practical engineering significance. I hope this should solve the ambiguty. I am in no way talking about the practical significance. Sometimes people should give some importance to theoretical questions like this one. It won't hurt anyone.

**Edit in response to answer by Shimao :**

I illustrate two examples of the infinite possible solutions (functions represented by network post training).

[image]

[image]

Out of the solutions A and B (both fit training data), one is extremely useful and the other is a totally useless. (These are two extreme examples.

(There is no mathematical proof that regularization by minimizing sum of weights solves this problem or make the problem have unique solution. The regularizations are thumb rules).

Comment: "this is not a subjective question" -> well, if you say so, I suppose this is then settled :D

Comment: more on the constructive side - I think you should rephrase your question to explain on what grounds you base this argument, so that people can respond to something concrete. You make 2 assertions, do you have either references or a logical argument to support either of them?

Comment: I will in a short while

Comment: Since deep learning is a subcategory of machine learning, the question doesn't make sense. Moreover, it is unclear (what do you mean by "knowing" and "believing", those are very broad and ambiguous). Moreover, it is about subjective claim. All this makes it off-topic.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju How did your brain (a sort of neural network) decide that one of those examples, from solutions A and B, is useful (or even extremely useful)?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : Before I answer your million dollar question,tell me,Do you mean both are equally useful?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : "How did your brain, decide that one of those examples, from solutions A and B, is useful (or even extremely useful)?"....... My main motive of my original post is to elicit this particular question in the reader's mind, and looks like I have succeeded. Now you are on the right track. "How do you know which of these infinite solutions is extremely useful, without actually testing on the test/validation data? That's the point... We should stop glorifying neural nets, and try to find an answer to this question. This is called "Looking Beyond Data..."

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I don't know what is useful by just looking at two images. I do not know what to expect. The context, which I do not know, is very important.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju what do you mean with "without actually testing on the test/validation data"? Are you making a straw man argument here, by arguing against the practice of not using testing and validation (which is a different independent case).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I mean without testing the corresponding neural net on test data

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju that does not make it more clear. Why does that (a wrong practice or bad use of neural nets) invalidate (in general) deep learning and neural nets?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : It means deeplearning/neural nets theory is incomplete. Its not even wrong. It is not subjective to proof. It says one of these solutions is useful, but doesnt tell which one, its upto designer to find it. So if the solution is not good, the designer takes the blame for not finding best solution. It does not tell apriori, the best solution.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju you are following a strawman argument or at least you seem to have a very particular restricted (wrong) use of deep learning in mind. Could you please clarify your question "better" (that means not with just more long-winded arguments and argumentum ad nauseum). The question is, as it is currently stated, refering to a very unclear background. Some real-world example (not two made up images that have no bearing on actual practice) could help.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : As I have clarified multiple times in my question edits and comments, This is a purely theoretical abstract question and need not have obviously seeable bearing on any practical situation. This is only a theoretical abstract analysis, and I dont think there is anything that needs clarification.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings : If you want some familiar examples, consider Linear regression or SVM, these concepts don't have this short coming. Only deep neural networks has this short coming. I hope it will be clear for you now.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju you can not say that it is clear because *you* think that it is clear (that is why I ask you for practical examples/ applications where we can see the failure of the theory being demonstrated, meaning you will make the interpretation of your question less/non ambiguous ). You say it it theoretical but you haven't written anything (formal) theoretic except for giving a vague idea. If you speak about usefull then you need to explain it. Well yes, maybe it is not complete in theory then, since this usefulness is a practical concept.

Answer (score 6):

> If you know about Science, then you will not believe in Physics. If
>   you believe in Physics, that means you don't understand Science.
>
> Reasons: The search space containing the physical laws which explain
>   our universe is infinite, and we don't know which grand unified theory
>   of physics generalizes the best (mind you, none of our grand unified
>   theories even explain gravity yet!).

I think you should relax your definition of "belief" from mathematical-proof levels of rigor to "does it work?". And deep learning works, so I "believe" in it. And I'm pretty sure I understand machine learning.

Hopefully, you would "believe" in physics not because physicists have finally got a Theory of Everything (they don't), but because physics is useful and necessary for a wide variety of modern technologies such as GPS, and also conveniently models how much of the universe works.

Comment: I will get to it with an interesting example. It will be interesting to say if you maintain the same argument.

Comment: Please see my examples.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju everyone already agrees that neural networks lack unique solutions, don't have rigorous theoretical foundations, etc. There is no controversy here. But then what is your question?